# If an exception is caught on the server side of an update panel, can you see the stack trace somehow?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to debug a third party library that is throwing an null reference exception in certain cases, but I am only getting the exception from the javascript side, which doesn't contain the stack trace in the error message.

Is there a value in the scriptmanager or something similar with more information about the exception, or should I be removing the update panels to get at the raw exception?

(Easier said then done, its nested several update panels deep)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [`ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.asyncpostbackerror.aspx) event.

You can do something like this

```
protected void ScriptManager1_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)
{
        //do something with the exception
        log(e.Exception.Message);

        // show a message to the user.
        ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackErrorMessage =
            "An  error occurred." + e.Exception.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off ajax features temporary by setting EnablePartialRendering property of the ScriptManager to false.